# Issue with states - was working but now returns an inscrutable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The app does indeed compile successfully, but my terminal returns TypeError: current is not defined. On my editor this refers to line 13, or where it says "temp: data.current.temp_f"

This prevents my app from making the API call.

All that works is removing this.state.lon, but is a roadblock I can't overcome.

//Data for the error code:

```js
async componentDidMount () {
    const url = `http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=03492304982049820498foifjoifjaoijfas39&q=${this.state.lon}`;
    const response = await fetch(url); 
    const data = await response.json(); 
    this.setState({temp: data.current.temp_f, loading: false});
    console.log(data);
  }
```

//Data for the component

```js
class LocaterLong extends React.Component {


        state = {lon: null, errorMessage:''}; 

        componentWillMount() {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => this.setState({lon: position.coords.longitude }), //pass an object, that updates a property 
                err => this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message}) 
            );    
        }
```

Before this error, I was able to successfully pull the necessary data and have it display. I am trying to pass the state "lon" as a prop into the url. When I remove this, the app works again, so I have definitely narrowed the issue down to something with states. My other suspicion is that is has to do with component lifecycles, and as a beginner something I'm still trying to wrap my head around. My other component is a long geolocation request. I used componentWillMount because it happened to work, even though originally the tutorial I referenced used DidMount.

The crazy thing about the problem I ran into is that initially, it did work. The long was successfully passed into the url, and changed that parameter to give me a location.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is `this.state.lon` is not **guaranteed** to be present (though it may be sometimes!) by the time `componentDidMount` is called.

I think you can simplify your state management a bit. Unless there's some other aspect of the component that requires the persistence of the `lon` value, you can just inline the fetch in the position callback, as below. Keep in mind that you should still handle when `data.current` is undefined or the response is otherwise empty or incomplete (maybe in the `loadData` function?)

(Note also that `componentWillMount` has been [marked for deprecation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) in recent releases of React.)

```
class LocaterLong extends React.Component {
  state = {errorMessage:''}; 

  async loadData(lon) {
    const url = `http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=03492304982049820498foifjoifjaoijfas39&q=${lon}`;
    const response = await fetch(url); 
    return response.json(); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async position => {
        const data = await loadData(position.coords.longitude);
        this.setState({ temp: data.current.temp_f, loading: false });
      },
      err => this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message}) 
    );  
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So I was going about it all wrong, and unless someone saw the mess I had besides this code, there's no way it would have been figured out. The first mistake was I tried to get a component to communicate with another component by passing a state as a prop through a render. (This.state.lon). When I said it worked, it actually didn't. For some reason, it rendered but the API url took my state declaration (State={loading:true, temp:null,) and output the nearest city name with "Null" in it. Did I mention I had separate comps for lat and long? :D Solution? Simple javascript function.